# Adding "Add Friend Button" anywhere in the buddypress site

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I'm trying to place an "Add Friend" button outside of the members page, inside a loop, so the button appears next to the author's avatar in a post.
I tried adding ;

```
<?php if ( bp_is_active( 'friends' ) ) { ?>

                        <?php bp_add_friend_button( $user_ids['users'][$i]->id ) ?>

                    <?php } ?>
```

Inside the loop but it didn't return any results.
Then I placed the following action hook in functions.php, it displayed the button inside the loop but once clicked, all the buttons in the post list got clicked as well.

```
 add_action( ‘the_content’, ‘bp_add_friend_button’, 5 );
```

So now I'm stuck. I thought, adding a template tag inside the template would work since it had worked for "Send Message" button.

Answer (score 1):

try

`<?php if ( function_exists( 'bp_add_friend_button' ) ) : ?>
                <?php bp_add_friend_button() ?>
            <?php endif; ?>`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that works for me, hope its helps.

```
$id_or_email = $result -> user_ID;
$avatar_default = get_avatar($id_or_email, $size, $default = '', $alt = '', $args = null);
$potential_friend_id = $id_or_email;
$friend_status = false;
$friend_button = bp_add_friend_button($potential_friend_id, $friend_status);
 echo '<li>'. $avatar_default. $user_info->user_nicename . $friend_button . '</li> ';
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a plugin that solve this, but to followup on Rafa's solution.
This complete code worked for me.

1. In bp-custom.php ( this is a file you need to create)

   ```
    function my_id_text_processor($friend_id)
    {
      //Return string id without 'uid-' attached
      $search = 'uid-';
      $replace_with = '';
      return  str_replace($search, $replace_with, $friend_id);

    }
   ```

   2. In the file you want the button to appear put this code.

   ```
    < ?php $friend_id = my_id_text_processor(bp_get_group_invite_item_id()) ? >


    $avatar_default = get_avatar($friend_id, $size, $default = '', $alt = '', $args = null);
    $friend_status = false;
    $friend_button = bp_add_friend_button($friend_id, $friend_status);
    echo '<li>'. $avatar_default,bp_group_invite_user_link(),$friend_button . '</li> ';
   ```